# Proving there exists such a polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, roots

I'm having trouble proving the following statement:

For all primes $p$, there exists a non-constant polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb Z_p[x]$ such that f(x) does not have a root in $\mathbb Z_p$

What I have tried so far is using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, which states that all polynomials $f(x)$ with $deg(f(x)) \ge 1$, there exists $x_0\in \mathbb C$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ assuming $f(z)$ has 0 roots, but that did not get me anywhere. Does anyone know of a way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  can you find a polynomial $g \in \mathbb Z_p[x]$, not equal to the zero polynomial, such that $g(x)$ nonetheless equals zero for all $x \in \mathbb Z_p$?  If so, you should be able to modify $g(x)$ to produce a polynomial that is never 0.

Comment: Are you talking about the integers mod $p$ or the $p$-adic integers when you say $\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra shouldn't be relevant here, because the statement you're proving says precisely that the FTA fails if you're working with polynomials over $\mathbb Z_p$ instead of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @RaviFernando : why ? doesn't the FTA in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$  say that if $f(a) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ then $f(x) \equiv (x-a) g(x) \pmod{p}$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 You're thinking of the remainder theorem

Comment: if thats the case then im not sure which theorem to use lol

Comment: @Bill Do you know Fermat's little theorem ?

Comment: yes but I have no idea how to use it for this question

Answer (score 3):

Write $f(x)=\Pi_{i\in Z_p}(X-i)+1$. It does not have a root.

Answer (score 2):

Over $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, there are $p^2$ polynomials of the form $x^2+ax+b$ but there are only $p(p+1)/2$ polynomials of the form $(x+a)(x+b)$, which leaves $p(p-1)/2$ irreducible degree $2$ polynomials.

Comment: typo aside, I think I have the right count, for example when $p=2$ there is only one irreducible polynomial of degree $2$, namely $x^2+x+1$

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat's theorem, all elements of $\mathbb Z_p$ are roots of $x^p-x$.

Therefore, $f(x)=x^p-x+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: I assume that $\mathbb Z_p = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.